# My loop is struggling to move first characters of string to end of string in print for length of string

Tags: python

the output if given a string, "abcdefg" of length 7 as example, should print out 7 lines like:

```
abcdefg
bcdefga
cdefgab
defgabc
efgabcd
fgabcde
gabcedf
```

but I seem to be missing the boat after many many hours of various loops and print statements

```
s = str("abcdefg")
print(s)
print()
for i in range(len(s)):
    new_s = s[:i+1] + s[-i:] + s[-i]
    print(new_s)
```

I get this:

```
abcdefg

aabcdefga
abgg
abcfgf
abcdefge
abcdedefgd
abcdefcdefgc
abcdefgbcdefgb
```

Comment: try to print the parts of the s string to debug your code instead of checking the final result

Answer (score 2):

You're overcomplicating this. The proper expression is just

```
new_s = s[i:] + s[:i]
```

slicing is inclusive of the start index, and exclusive of the end index. This above expression guarantees to keep the length of the result the same as the input list, just swapping variable parts of it.

Note that the first `new_s` value is the original string itself. No need to print it at the start of the program.

The result is:

```
abcdefg
bcdefga
cdefgab
defgabc
efgabcd
fgabcde
gabcdef
```

slicing in detail: [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Comment: thank you. Definately was overcomplicating this and just kept getting worse.  Your the best

Answer (score 0):

the loop could be like:

```
s_len = len(s)
for i in range(s_len):
    s = s[1:] + s[0]
    print(s)
```